# Finding $\sum_{r=0}^{2n+1}(-1)^{r}{2n+1\choose r}^2$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I have to find the value of the following sum involving binomial coefficients. According to what I have solved, the answer should be $0$ but as per the answers given it is $1$. It would be great if someone could identify the error.

> $$\sum_{r=0}^{2n+1}(-1)^{r}{2n+1\choose r}^2$$

---

Consider the following expansions. The required summation is then just the coefficient of $x^{2n+1}$ in $(1+x)^{2n+1}[-(x-1)^{2n+1}]$ as can be seen from the following.

$$\begin{aligned}(1+x)^{2n+1}&={2n+1\choose 0}+{2n+1\choose 1}x+{2n+1\choose 2}x^2+\ldots\\ -(x-1)^{2n+1}&={2n+1\choose 0}x^{2n+1}-{2n+1\choose 1}x^{2n}+{2n+1\choose 2}x^{2n-1}-+\ldots\end{aligned}$$

Now the coefficient of $x^{2n+1}$ in $(1-x^2)^{2n+1}$ would be $0$, since only even degree terms are present in its expansion. So the answer should be $0$. Can anyone identify the error. Thanks.

Comment: $0$ is the correct answer. Also easy to see after $r\mapsto 2n+1-r$.

Comment: For $n=0$, $(-1)^0\binom10^2 + (-1)^1\binom11^2 = 0$, so the answer should be zero. You can obtain the same result by splitting the sum to from $0$ to $n$ and from $n+1$ to $2n+1$.

Comment: @metamorphy That would be a lot quicker. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\sum_{r = 0}^{2n + 1}
\pars{-1}^{r}{2n + 1 \choose r}^{2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{r = 0}^{2n + 1}
\pars{-1}^{\pars{2n + 1} - r}
\,\,\,{2n + 1 \choose \pars{2n + 1} - r}^{2}
\\[5mm] = &\
\color{red}{-}\sum_{r = 0}^{2n + 1}
\pars{-1}^{r}{2n + 1 \choose r}^{2}
\\[5mm] &\
\implies
\bbx{\sum_{r = 0}^{2n + 1}
\pars{-1}^{r}{2n + 1 \choose r}^{2} = 0} \\ &
\end{align}